# Looking for best rendition

Tags: translation, word-choice

Today when  aboard a bus, I heard the following "车开了请扶稳坐好" from the paging, and the English version was also given "The bus is leaving, please hold steady and sit well." Obviously, such an expression is far from making sense.

And also I saw a sentence in a notice, which says "在大厅前集体乘车前往”, and the English is given as "take a bus in front of the lobby", which needs revision as well.

Comment: Are you asking for a better translation for both?

Comment: possible English: 1.... hold on (to straps or other supports) and be seated! 2.在大厅前集体乘车前往. As a group (collectively) proceed to board the bus in front of the lobby.

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: @as4s4hetic To be or not to be, that is a question, do you mean that?

Answer (score 1):

"车开了请扶稳坐好" - " Bus is now leaving, please sit down or hold on to safety handrail "

"在大厅前集体乘车前往” - "Please gather in front of the main hall for groups departure"

Comment: If you stay in China, you know 扶稳and坐好 are two acts conducted individually and separately by passengers either standing or having a seat. Warm-hearted netizens of other sites also give their answers to the same questions, I will show you later on.

Comment: @NanningYouth, considering you are a native of English and also understand the sentences very well, you should render them better than any of us I believe.